# Regular expression that does not allow sequential repetition of the same character

Tags: regex

How can I express these rules in a single regular expression?

1. More than two repetitions of a character is invalid
2. Two repetitions of characters following each other directly are invalid (`aabcc` is valid, `oott` is not)

Comment: People are quick to downvote these days and they don't cut you any slack for being new.   Always try to at least make an attempt and if you can't get it then post what you've tried and people will help you correct it or point you in a better direction.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, you don't give your language, but assuming it supports lookaheads you can try this:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1{2})(?!.*(.)\2(.)\3).+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?300ci)

There are two parts, the first part `^.+$` matches any character from the start of the string till the end, needs at least one character because of the `+`.

The second part are the negative lookaheads. They define a set of rules and the complete regex fails as soon as one of them matches.

`(?!.*(.)\1{2})` fails on 3 equal characters in a row.

`(?!.*(.)\2(.)\3)` fails on your second condition "Two repetitions of characters following each other directly"

The `\1` (23) are backreferences to the parts in brackets before.

Comment: +1 (although of course you don't actually need the `.+$` part except for visualization on Regexr).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/([a-z])\1/gi` to check for duplicate characters and afterwards check for the amount of matches. If it is greater than 1, you have mulitple duplicate characters.

Comment: This doesn't distinguish between `aabcc` and `oott`.